# Is $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ continuous at $0 \implies $ continuos at $a$?(proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

This is a simple proof of Real Analysis in a single variable.

Given $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$  $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Show that if $f $ is continuos at $x=0$ then $ f$ is continuos at$ x=a$.

Hint or suggestion: make a change of variable $u=x-a$.

Please verify my proof:

Let $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$
So $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x+y)=f(0)f(y)$

Let $\epsilon>0$ exists such that $\delta>0$

We have:
 $0<|x-0|< \delta$  $\implies$
  $$|f(x+y)-f(x)f(y)|<\epsilon$$

(by definition of continuity)

So, let $u=x-a \implies u\rightarrow x-a$

Such that $x\rightarrow 0$ and $u-a \rightarrow 0$
$\implies u\rightarrow a$

Then, we get the limit:

$$lim_{u \rightarrow a} f(u-a+y)=f(u-a)f(y)$$

Therefore $\epsilon>0$ exists when $\delta>0$  such that   $0<|u-a|<\delta$
it implies
$$|f(u-a+y)-f(u-a)f(y)|<\epsilon$$

$\therefore  f $ 
is continuos at 
$x=0 \implies$ $f$ is continuous at $x=a_{\blacksquare}$
Is it correct?.

Suggestions will be  welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your understanding of $\epsilon-\delta$ definition is wrong. It quite the other way round. It says whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x+a)-f(x)|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Γιάννης Παπαβασιλείου already gave a nice answer, I add another interesting fact. It is known that the exponential $f(x) = a^x$ is the unique function with $f(1) = a$ that satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$. Since it is continuous you have your statement.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)= \lim\limits_{u\to0}f(u+x_0)=\lim\limits_{u\to0}[f(u)f(x_0)]=\lim\limits_{u\to0}f(u)\lim\limits_{u\to0}f(x_0)=f(0)f(x_0)=f(0+x_0)=f(x_0)$ so $f$ is continous at $x=x_0\checkmark$

Comment: Indeed. I have replaced $a$ with $x_0$

Comment: Why did I make a wrong change of variable? I set $u=x-x_0$ then $u\to u_0=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}(x-x_0)=0$ and $x=u+x_0$

Comment: @Malu I'm sorry but I can't follow you. Is there something you want me to explain further?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Malu Is my answer complete or do you want me to add something else?

Comment: No, thank you. Here is my suggestion: you re a great mathematician, but you need to explain a little bit more when you help begginers. In this case you had provided a solution but you didnt explain "the nature" of your proof. It was difficult for me at first sight to understand it. So that's my advice for you. But yeah, it helps a lot. I couldnt do it bymyself.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I'm not a great mathematician :)